# Floating and non-floating items in one document

Tags: tables, floats

till now my tables were like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}    
\begin{minipage}[h!]{\linewidth}    
\centering    
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}}
    \hline    
     \rule{0pt}{8pt}    
     \textbf{column a} & \textbf{column b} & \textbf{column c} \\      
        \hline    
        \rule{0pt}{8pt}    
        text    &   text        & text   \\    
        \rule{0pt}{8pt}    
        text    &   text        & text   \\
        \hline    
        \rule{0pt}{8pt}    
        text    &   text        & text   \\    
    \hline    
    \hline    
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{text for the listing}{caption} \label{tab:table}     
    \end{minipage}    
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

well, the problem is, that some table's appear above the caption. My idea was to put these ones in a non-floating environment. Since I have more than 60 figures and tables I don't want to change them all in a `tabular` or `tabularx`-environment.

Is there a way to put some figures or tables in a non-floating-environment AND to leave the rest in a `table` - environment.

With: `\captionof`....

And they need to be numbered =(

Comment: Change `table` by `center` and use `\captionof`

Comment: `\begin{minipage}[h!]{\linewidth}   ` isn't doing anything: a `linewidth` wide minipage in a table takes up the whole table and minipage does not have an optional argument that takes `[h!]` that syntax would be legal 9but generate a warning) if used on the `table` environment.

Comment: There is no need to use captionof _inside_ a table: just use `\caption`

Comment: Your question is not clear: you say that some tables appear above the caption, but latex does not move the caption relative to the tabular: if you put the caption below the tabular as here, it will always come below it in the output

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to mix-and-match the use of a floating and non-floating `figure` or `table`, then you should use the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float)'s `[H]` float specifier. Here's a small example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{float,lipsum,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[H]% Non-floating figure float
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width = .7\linewidth, height = 50pt]{example-image-a}
  \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}[t]% Regular floating figure
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width = .7\linewidth, height = 50pt]{example-image-b}
  \caption{Another figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

The above works for any of the default floats (`figure` and `table`, as well as new ones defined via the `float` package). Additionally, there's no need for using [`capt-of`](http://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) as the floats provide sufficient `\caption`ing.

The above example also highlights one of the problems of mixing non-floating floats with other/regular floats. The numbering will still work, but the visual placement of numbering might be mixed (Figure 2 has floated to the top of the page, visually appearing *before* the non-floating Figure 1 which was placed `[H]`ERE).

Comment: The space before and after the non-float table will be the same the float table environment.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with `captionof`? Just put your non-floating `tabular` in a `minipage` and use `captionof`. Maybe I'm missing something? I'm using this in a document currently, and it's working fine.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}}
    \hline    
     \rule{0pt}{8pt}    
     \textbf{column a} & \textbf{column b} & \textbf{column c} \\      
        \hline    
        \rule{0pt}{8pt}    
        text    &   text        & text   \\    
        \rule{0pt}{8pt}    
        text    &   text        & text   \\
        \hline    
        \rule{0pt}{8pt}    
        text    &   text        & text   \\    
    \hline    
    \hline    
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{text for the listing}{caption} \label{tab:table}
\end{minipage}



\end{document}
```